# Multiple Nested dictionary From a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dependent nested dictionary from a loop.
Suppose this is my list

```
for i in compatibility:
    print(i.os_id, i.python_id, i.ml_id)
```

If I print this one then I will get data something similar to this

output :

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
```

What I want is I want to make it a nested 3 level dictionary and for this output the dictionary will be something like this:

```
{1: {1: {1,2}, 2: {1,2}}, 2: {1: {1}, 2: {2,3}}}
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Output is not a dictionary. It is a list that I looped through and get these values

Comment: they were referencing your sample output, which appears to have sets as the innermost values.

Comment: From my output I want to make a dictionary like If I say for 1 1 1 and 1 1 2
the dictionary will be like {1 : {1 : [1,2]}} similar to this

Comment: That's a list, not a set, but your question uses sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments I used lists in output:

```py
data = [
    ["1", "1", "1"],
    ["1", "1", "2"],
    ["1", "2", "1"],
    ["1", "2", "2"],
    ["2", "1", "1"],
    ["2", "2", "2"],
    ["2", "2", "3"],
]

out = {}
for a, b, c in data:
    out.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, []).append(c)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{"1": {"1": ["1", "2"], "2": ["1", "2"]}, "2": {"1": ["1"], "2": ["2", "3"]}}
```

---

If you want sets in output:

```py
out = {}
for a, b, c in data:
    out.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, set()).add(c)
```

---

EDIT: Removed `collections.defaultdict`